# How can use WM_LBUTTONUP with ON_WM_PARENTNOTIFY()

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a window containing a list. When more than one item is highlighted I want a button to become visible to be pushed over another button. If it goes back to one or none highlighted I want the button to be disabled and the previous button to be shown again.

Currently I have a OnParentNotify function

```
if(message = LBUTTONDOWN)
int count = pMyListControl->GetSelectedCount();
    if(count>1)
        {
        pTotalBox->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
        pCheckBut->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        count=0;
        }
    else
        {
        pTotalBox->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        pCheckBut->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
        count = 0;
        }
```

This approach is working somewhat. If I click one item, nothing happens, as wanted. But if I select 2, nothing happens still. It isn't until I select another, after selecting at least 2, that it works correctly.

So I understand it is only getting the count of items prior to being clicked. I need it to get items already selected, AND items selected when performing a click.

Comment: `(message = LBUTTONDOWN)` is an *assignment*, you want `(message == LBUTTONDOWN)` for a *comparison* instead. Also, why are you handling `LBUTTONDOWN` to detect a change in item states? You should handle [`LVN_ITEMCHANGED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-itemchanged) in the parent's `OnNotify` instead. Items can be (de)selected using the keyboard, not just the mouse.

Comment: Sorry assignment was a typo. Yes, I'm using LBUTTONDOWN because there are multiple other things that the click does, not just highlighting them. It pulls up the data in another window, and there is also an image along with the item for showing it checked or unchecked.

Comment: This is what happens when you don't *copy/paste* your actual code. Because there are other mistakes in the code shown, like missing `{}` braces on the 1st `if`

Comment: You can (and should) use `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` for all of that stuff, not `LBUTTONDOWN`. `LBUTTONDOWN` is triggered before the ListView updates its state, which is why you are not seeing `GetSelectedCount()` updated. `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` is triggered after each state change. It even tells you *which* item was changed, and *how* it was changed.

Comment: Ok. I'm using the WM_LBUTTONDOWN as a parameter though. for WM_PARENTNOTIFY. I don't think that accepts LVN_ITEMCHANGED as a parameter

Comment: As I stated in my original comment, `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` will arrive in the parent's `OnNotify()` (`WM_NOTIFY`) method, not in the `OnParentNotify()` (`WM_PARENTNOTIFY`) method.

Comment: Ok I think I'm understanding better. Sorry I'm not very experienced. Using LVN_ITEMCHANGED would just be used with a new WM_NOTIFY message correct.  Then I'd create a new function to call for that which has the GetSelectedCount. Is that the right idea?

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. I'll try this now